# ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: syntax error

Tags: gstreamer

I'm working on a project and i need to make this work

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
  videomixer name=mix \
      sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::alpha=0 \
      sink_1::xpos=640 sink_1::ypos=0 sink_1::alpha=1 \
      sink_2::xpos=0   sink_2::ypos=0 sink_2::alpha=1 \
    ! glshader location=distortion.frag ! glimagesink sync=false \
  videotestsrc pattern="black" \
      ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 \
      ! mix.sink_0 \
  rtpbin name=rtpbinleft latency=250 ntp-sync=true do-retransmission=0 \
    udpsrc caps=application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264 port=5000 ! rtpbinleft.recv_rtp_sink_0 \
      rtpbinleft. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale add-borders=false ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=720 ! mix.sink_1 \
    udpsrc port=5001 ! rtpbinleft.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
      rtpbinleft.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5005 host=192.168.0.17 sync=false async=false \
  rtpbin name=rtpbinright latency=250 ntp-sync=true do-retransmission=0 \
    udpsrc caps=application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264 port=6000 ! rtpbinright.recv_rtp_sink_0 \
      rtpbinright. ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale add-borders=false ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=720 ! mix.sink_2 \
    udpsrc port=6001 ! rtpbinright.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
      rtpbinright.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=6005 host=192.168.0.18 sync=false async=false
```

it's supposed totake to streams and apply a barrel distortion.
Here is the tuto :https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=65700&start=25

I've tried almost everything but it allways fail and say

```
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: syntax error.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you've just forgot the enclosing quotation marks in the caps values of the rtpbin's elements. In a command line you must do like:

```
rtpbin caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264"
```

Out of the quotations all the '(string)', '(int)' are not making sense to gst-launch.